# Django Wagtail: Is it bad practise access data using own object.method instead of rewriting object.get_context method?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, wagtail

I am playing with **Django Wagtail**. Concerning rendering data in templates, I know that official way is rewrite get_context method in my page object. But I can just write my own method, I find it better and more clear for me. Just want to ask if this is possible way how to do that or is there any problem, catch, performance issues?
Thank you very much.

**standard way:**

```
class Blog(Page): 
    template = "blog/blog.html"        

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        get_posts = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at').all()
        context['list_all'] = get_posts
        return context
```

**using own method:**

```
class Blog(Page): 
    template = "blog/blog.html"        

    def list_all(self):
       get_posts = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at').all()
       return (get_posts)
```

**Render in template - standard way:**

```
  {% for post in list_all %}
      {{post.title}}
  {% endfor %}
```

**Render in template - own method:**

```
  {% for post in self.list_all %}
      {{post.title}}        
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are fine. The only real disadvantage of using a method is that you don't have easy access to the request object, so (for example) you won't be able to implement a listing that's paginated or filtered based on URL parameters that way.

Putting your business logic in methods also means that you can potentially use it in other places besides template rendering, such as [outputting it over the API](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html#adding-custom-page-fields) or [using it in search indexing](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/search/indexing.html#indexing-callables-and-other-attributes).